# Plotting two variables from multiple lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Given a few lists as below

```
    l1 = {x1 -> 0.5, x2 -> 0.7, x3 -> 0.1, x4 -> 1};
l2 = {x1 -> 0.5, x2 -> 0.7, x3 -> 0.2, x4 -> 1.1};
l3 = {x1 -> 0.5, x2 -> 0.7, x3 -> 0.3, x4 -> 1.2};
l4 = {x1 -> 0.5, x2 -> 0.7, x3 -> 0.4, x4 -> 1.3};
```

How can one plot `x3` vs `x4` from these? I am dealing with a large number of such lists, so its not possible to copy past the entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your lists are together in one larger list like this,

```
lists = {l1, l2, l3, l4, <... potentially many more lists ...>};
```

then you can use `Lookup` to extract the data you need and just plot it with `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[Lookup[lists, {x3, x4}]]
```

Or if you just want to reference the individual lists:

```
ListPlot[Lookup[{l1, l2, l3, l4}, {x3, x4}]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @lericr, that's simple and elegant! Just on more thing. How about if I want plot, say, x1+x2 vs x3+x4 ?

Comment: One way would be to use the strategy @ydd showed: `ListPlot[{x1 + x2, x3 + x4} /. lists]`. You could also run a query-operator on your data. What's best kinda depends on the semantics of your lists, the origin of your lists, and the context of your situation.

Answer (score 4):

If I am understanding correctly, you have a large number of lists that look like  {x1 -> val1, x2 -> val2, x3 -> val3, x4 -> val4}. But if you gave them all variable names by hand (l1, l2 ,l3,etc.) it can't be a huge amount of lists. I would make a list of the lists and then use `ReplaceAll` to get the x3 and x4 values from each list

```
data = {l1, l2, l3, l4};
ListPlot[{x4,x3} /. data];
```

You probably want to make a list of the lists right from the start, instead of having a bunch of lists with separate variable names.